# Spring returns null beans after initialization

Tags: java, spring, rmi

I have a situation I cannot explain. 
I am trying to create a RMI server that will call Spring services, but I cannot bind the beans to the rmi registry because they all are nulls.
The code is like this:

```
public class RMIServer {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RMIServer.class);

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws RemoteException, AlreadyBoundException {
        final Registry registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(RmiConstants.RMI_PORT);
        final ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(RmiConfiguration.class);
        for (final String key : ctx.getBeansOfType(BaseRmi.class).keySet()) {
            LOG.info("Registering {}...", key);
            registry.bind(key, (BaseRmi) ctx.getBean(key));
        }
        LOG.info("RMI server was started...");
    }
}
```

The Spring configuration class is:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({ "classpath*:app-context.xml" })
public class RmiConfiguration {

   @Bean
   AccountRmi accountRmi() {
     try {
        return new AccountRmiImpl();
     } catch (final RemoteException e) {
        return null;
     }
   }
}
```

The bean that I want to instantiate is this:

```
public class AccountRmiImpl extends BaseRmi implements AccountRmi {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 5798106327227442204L;

  private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AccountRmiImpl.class.getName());

  @Autowired
  private AccountService accountService;

  public AccountRmiImpl() throws RemoteException {
    super();
  }

  @Override
  public List<PersonType> getPersonTypes() throws AppException {
    return accountService.getPersonTypes();
  }
}
```

The `BaseRmi` is:

```
public abstract class BaseRmi extends UnicastRemoteObject {

    protected BaseRmi() throws RemoteException {
        super();
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9115163829282749718L;
}
```

The interface for this bean is this:

```
public interface AccountRmi extends AccountFacade, java.rmi.Remote {

}
```

where the `AccountFacade` contains the business logic.

What I saw is that if I remove the `java.rmi.Remote` interface on the AccountRmi interfaces declaration the bean gets instantiated but I need that interface for the remote lookup. No errors are getting displayed in the logs. Does spring has a limitation for multiple interfaces on a bean declaration or it's just because of the java.rmi.Remote interfaces ?
I can provide further details if requested.

Many thanks,
Daniel

Comment: Do you have a @Component anywhere ?

Comment: The configuration creates the beans. I don't think I need to put the annotation on the AccountRmiImpl but I will try. Thanks

Comment: You're masking `RemoteException` exceptions in your @Bean method. That doesn't seem prudent. If in fact the bean is required, why would you hide any constructor exceptions.

Comment: You are right. I will make some changes about this. Also the facade methods need to throw the RemoteException exception, even though I have the AppException extending the RemoteException. Why is that ? Thanks